# UWP OnBackgroundActivated with PushNotificationTrigger (raw notification)

Tags: c#, background, uwp, push

In my current UWP project trying to get OnBackgroundActivated() triggered via a raw push notification. Registration is as follows:

```
var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
builder.Name = taskName;
builder.SetTrigger(new PushNotificationTrigger());
BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();
```

When the app is attached to Visual Studio and in state "Resume" (active), then OnBackgroundActivated() gets called when I send a raw notification. I can see that using System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine().

When the app is attached to Visual Studio and in state "Suspend" (not active), then OnBackgroundActivated() does not get called. But as soon as I change the state back to "Resume" OnBackgroundActivated() gets called with the raw notification that I have sent while the app was not active. It's like the raw notification gets queued until the app becomes active again.

Why doesn't OnBackgroundActivated() fire immediately while the app is not active? I thought that's the main purpose of this functionality.

Comment: Are you using this [OnBackgroundActivated method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.onbackgroundactivated.aspx)? Do you use [single process model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-an-inproc-background-task) to implement `PushNotificationTrigger`?

Comment: Yes, single process model.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. In my side, `OnBackgroundActivated` method gets called even I changed Lifetime Management event to "Suspend". What's the OS version you are using? Could you share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

late to the party but still, maybe this will save 2 days for someone. I was facing the same issue and the fix in my case was to change target device family in appxmanifest to 14393 minimum.

change

```
<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Mobile" MinVersion="10.0.10586.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.10586.0" />
```

to

```
<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Mobile" MinVersion="10.0.14393.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.14393.0" />
```

for all nodes. Strange thing is that if you do not use specific Device families, but rather Universal, then you can leave it on `10.0.00000.0` and it works.